# How to suppress repeated alert/notification sounds

Tags: notifications, audio, alerts

Is there a way to suppress repeated alert sounds within a certain period of time - i.e after an event triggers a sound, do not play any further sounds for any more of the same event type that arrives in the following 30/60/90 seconds.

e.g
I'm chatting to someone on Google Talk on my PC, every time they send a me message my phone chirps at me. I don't want to silence it completely (maybe they go afk for 5 mins and I'd like the sound to inform me of when they come back), I just don't want the repeated noises. The result being that during a conversation my phone only makes a sound once a minute, rather than going off every few seconds.

Google Talk is just one example, but a method of suppressing all repeated alert sounds would be ideal.

*I'm using Jelly Bean on a Motorola RAZR i, but answers for any version of android would be welcome*

Comment: Good example, I always end up killing Google Talk's notification sounds because of that

Comment: We're now in 2024 and most phones don't have this feature. Repetitive notifications are extremely infuriating, especially if that one person sends 5-6 messages in a row, which happens frequently. That's the reason my phone is on mute all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Muting notifications from the same app within a set period is not yet available in stock Android.

However, some custom ROMs have already implemented this option. If your ROM has this functionality, the option would be under **Settings > Sounds > Less frequent notification sounds**. Note that the name of this option may differ from ROM to ROM.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Xposed the Module [Less frequent notifications](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ofnitz.xless) will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned Google Talk (now Hangouts), but my answer would not really relate to that, but to the question itself, specifically when dealing with SMS.

You could use Tasker to mute the notification audio volume which is triggered by receiving an SMS for a certain period of time from a certain sender.

Note though, that this would modify the notification volume for all apps, not just SMS.